# Basic question about rent (this sort of question is arguable for my mate)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

If the rent for a house is £895 per month and is being rented by 2 people. One is accepted to pay £20 more per week, what is going to be monthly payment for each of those people?

Is it going to be £407.50 for one and £487.50 for the other OR £367.50 and £527.50 for the other?

I'm pretty sure it's the first statement.

**@edit**

The second has been calculated by my mate who is arguing that £895/2 = 447.50 and £447.50 - £80 = £367.50        and       447.50 + £50 = £527.50.

My logic is £895 - 80 = £815      £815 / 2 = £407.50      £407.50 + £80 = £487.50   for one      and the rest for the other.

Comment: How many weeks are there in a month? What should be the difference between the individual contributions?

Comment: 4 weeks in a month. One has accepted to pay £20 more per week than the other. Please see my edits.

Comment: The problem is that there are 12 months in a year but it's also 52 weeks and one or two extra days. So what is the monthly payment for each person? If you consider 4 weeks in a month then the first statement is the right one.

Comment: @Lazio Presuming a month is considered to be 4 weeks, tell your mate that the first person pays $121.875$, while the other pays $101.875= 121.875-20$ pounds every week. Hence, the first one pays $121.875 \times 4 = 487.5$, and the other one pays $101.875 \times 4 = 407.5$.

Comment: Let's not care about weeks in a year and focus on just 4 weeks a month. The monthly payment for the entire rent is £895. They are both sharing the property and one is accepted to pay £20 more per week than the other.

Comment: @Math Lover He claims that's absolutely wrong and it's okay when one person pays £91.875 and the other £131.87 per week. Just by looking at it, you are able to see the £40 per week difference... He also claims that £160 difference is obvious as you take £80 from one half and add £80 to the other...

Comment: @Lazio This website is not for settling disagreements between people. You asked a question and got the answer.

Comment: OK, so let's say there are 4 payments each month, you can use this equation $4(x+x+20)=895$, $8x=895-80$, $4x=407.5$ as you noticed

Answer (score 0):

The rent for the house is $895$ per month, which is $\frac{895}4=223.75$ per week (assuming $4$ weeks per month exactly)

We have two people, paying $x$ and $y$ amounts each per week. We know that person $y$ pays $20$ more a week, $x=y+20$, and that the amounts $x$ and $y$ pay must add up to the total for the week, $x+y = 223.75$

Solving this we can see that \begin{align}x+y&=223.75\\
(y+20)+y&=223.75\\
2y&=203.75\\
y&=101.875\end{align}

This then gives us that $x=121.875$

Over the month, then we can say that person $x$ pays $121.875\times 4 = 487.50$ and person $y$ pays $101.875\times 4 = 407.50$

Comment: The number of weeks in a month is not 4.  It is (365/7)/12=4.345238... in a  non-leap year.

Comment: Let's not be as precise. Pretend there are 4 weeks in a month.

Comment: @Lazio. whether I will or won't  may depend on which  tenant  I am. :)

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Hence my statement ‘assuming 4 weeks per month exactly’

Comment: @MathLover Corrected them - my fault for writing it while slightly distracted

Answer (score -1):

In a non-leap year there are $(365/7)$ weeks.

$(365/7)$(weeks/year) $\times$ ($1$ year/ $12$ months)$\times$ ($20$ clams / week)$=86.905$ clams/month.

So one of you pays $43.45$ clams more than $1/2$ of the monthly rent for $3/4$ of the months and pays $43.46$ clams more than $1/2$ of the monthly rent every fourth month. As long as you don't care about farthings.

You have 2 years and 1 month to figure out what to do in 2020, a leap year.